# Generate variables from a loop using SASS

Tags: css, list, loops, variables, sass

I'm writing a flexible Sass grid structure and I'm wanting to know if it's possible to generate variables from a loop in Sass.

Currently I have the following, which works for a 12 column grid:

```
$columns: 12;
$col-width: 100%/$columns;

$col-1: $col-width;
$col-2: $col-width*2;
$col-3: $col-width*3;
$col-4: $col-width*4;
$col-5: $col-width*5;
$col-6: $col-width*6;
$col-7: $col-width*7;
$col-8: $col-width*8;
$col-9: $col-width*9;
$col-10: $col-width*10;
$col-11: $col-width*11;
$col-12: $col-width*12;
```

I would then apply the variables like so:

```
.sidebar {
    width: $col-4;
}

.main-col {
    width: $col-8;
}
```

However, if I wanted 10 column grid I'd need to manually go in a edit this each time. Not a huge amount of work but if I can use a loop to generate the variables for me it would be better.

Here's the ideal scenario:

```
$columns: 12;

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
   $col-#{$i}: ($i / $columns) * 100%;
}
```

I could then tweak the `$columns` variable according to my grid structure. I'm not 100% sure this even achievable using Sass. But it would be great if it was.

See a gist here for an example: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/feecef8655dadd54f438e67e6c27dd0c

Any help would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use either `@mixin` or `@function` to achieve your goal.

`@mixin` example(http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins):

```
$columns: 12;

@mixin col($num) {
  width:100% / $columns * $num;
}

.sidebar {
  @include col(4);
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.main-col {
  @include col(8);
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```

`@function` example(http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#functions):

```
$columns: 12;    

@function col($num) {
  @return 100% / $columns * $num;;
}

.sidebar {
  width: col(4);
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.main-col {
  width: col(8);
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```